# Convert the Polar Equation to Cartesian Coordinates

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

$$
r^2=\sec 4\theta
$$

I graphed this equations using Wolfram Alpha and found it to be 2 hyperbolas.  I'm having difficulty showing this using the standard equations

$$
x=r\cos\theta \;, \; y=r\sin\theta \;, and \; x^2 +y^2 =r^2
$$

My work so far:

$$
r^2 = \sec4\theta=\frac{1}{\cos4\theta}=\frac{1}{\cos(2\theta+2\theta)}=\frac{1}{\cos2\theta \cos2\theta - \sin2\theta\sin2\theta} \\ \\ =\frac{1}{1-8\sin^2\theta + 8\sin^4\theta}
$$

I'm getting nowhere from here.  I've tried using a few other trig identities, but no luck!  Can one please point me in the right direction?  I would appreciate any help.  Thank you!!!

Comment: look at the graph of $r^ = sec 4\theta$.  looks like there $8$ branches of hyperbola. so cartesian equation is bound to be complicated.

Comment: I solved this while the others had posted their answers and I came to the conclusion that $$r^2 = \frac{1}{8\cos^4 \theta - 8\cos^2 \theta + 1}$$ using double angle rules for $\cos (x)$.

Comment: @ Mohammad Ali Baydoun I believe you can get that from using the identity $\cos2\theta = 2\cos^2\theta - 1$ where I had used $\cos2\theta = 1-2\sin^2\theta$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint
$$\dfrac{y^2}{x^2}=\tan^2{\theta}=\dfrac{\sin^2{\theta}}{1-\sin^2{\theta}}\Longrightarrow \sin^2{\theta}=\dfrac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}$$
and you have
$$x^2+y^2=r^2=\dfrac{1}{1-8\sin^2{\theta}+8\sin^4{\theta}}=\dfrac{1}{1-\dfrac{8y^2}{x^2+y^2}+8\left(\dfrac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right)^2}$$
so
$$x^2+y^2=\dfrac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2-8y^2(x^2+y^2)+8y^4}$$
so
$$\Longrightarrow x^4+y^4-6x^2y^2=x^2+y^2$$

Comment: Damnit.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

i can take $$r^2 =\frac{1}{1-8\sin^2\theta + 8\sin^4\theta}$$ and turn it into a cartesian equation.

$\begin{align}
1 &=\frac{r^2}{r^4-8r^4\sin^2\theta + 8r^4\sin^4\theta}\\
  &=\dfrac{(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2 - 8(x^2+y^2)y^2 +8y^4}\\
  &= \dfrac{(x^2+y^2)}{x^4 + y^4-6x^2y^2}\\
\end{align}$